# Using GDI+ in console application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exif

I am trying to write an application that change meta data in an image. I am using GDI+ for this as I could not find any other library that can easily be integrated into visual studio for this task.

Is there any such library?

When  tried this, I am getting error during linkage that some functions are missing (for example GdipCreateBitmapFromFile ).

What should I change in project setting to fix this?

Comment: The error that you are getting is probally because you did not include the right lib files.

Comment: @Caesar: Yes, but which library missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yes, but which library missing?

GdiPlus.lib is missing.  It is not one of the anointed SDK libs that are linked by default, like kernel32.lib.  Short from adding it to the linker's Additional Dependencies setting, the easiest way is to inject the linker directive with a #pragma in your source code:

```
#include <gdiplus.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib")
```